# Can I remove the gray triangle in the lower right of a contact icon?

Tags: contacts, app-widgets, contact-shortcut

I added a contact widget to the home screen of my Droid Razr M (running stock Android 4.1.1), and the icon has a little gray triangle in the lower right corner. Is there a way I can remove that from the image? I see these little triangles in my contacts list also.

**Update:** Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing (it took me a bit to figure out how to take it):

[image: Contact icon with gray triangle in lower right]

If it's any additional help, my contacts don't seem to sync properly, and I don't know why. When I go to *Settings > Accounts - Google > {My account}*, I see the "refresh" icon next to "Contacts." The last sync date for that item is older than all of the other items on the list. I've manually cleared the "Contacts Storage" data, and did a resync that way, but subsequent sync attempts seem to fail.

Comment: How do you mean *little gray triangle*, unless that's a google sync error on the contact?

Comment: Maybe you can add/link a screenshot to make this clearer?

Comment: What is *the contact widget*?

Comment: It's a little 1x1 widget that allows you access to a particular person in your contacts list. Apparently, it's the only way Motorola allows you to have a shortcut to a contact on the home screen.